# Combining two files into a single in windows command only result in the first file being copied

Tags: windows

This should be a fairly straightforward operation, but I'm puzzled as to why it is not working.

The following commands in windows results in only the first file being copied to destination file report.rtf

```
copy /b *.rtf report.rtf
```

or

```
type *.rtf >> report.rtf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a second file to an existing file, try

```
copy /b report.rtf+secondFile.rtf report.rtf
```

The "+" should combine them (assuming by "combine" you mean "concatenate").

Changing the `report.rtf` at the end to another file will let you put them into a new file, of course.

**NOTE:** In Windows 8.1 (and probably Windows 7 and Windows 8) doing this as a normal user will not work! Instead, run cmd.exe (command prompt) as an Administrator (right-click, Run as Administrator).

Comment: yes I mean concatenate. Thanks for the answer, but I still get the same result, only the content of the first file found is copied

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I had only tested this on Windows Vista, and I first heard of this being used on Windows 98. After testing on Windows 8.1, I experienced the same problem. I didn't realize that a command so innocuous would require Administrator privileges in newer versions of Windows, but, evidently, it does.

Comment: Good info to know. I had no idea this requires admin rights cause of the documents that I read did not mention it. Thank youa again.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you think its adequate. Thanks.

Comment: It actually did not work even when running it in a script as an administrator. I may have to write java code instead of doing it through the command line.